# Debugging Lock Pairs function in CS50 Tideman Question

Tags: c, cs50

My lock pairs function throws the following error:
:( Lock pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle.

```
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
// pairs[0].winner = 0 --> preferences[pairs[0].winner][pairs[0].loser] = someint
// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    int swap_counter = -1;
// iterate through pairs array, which is an array of struct (winner/loser)
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        swap_counter = 0;
// Compares first pair found to second pair found in pairs array. If first pair is smaller victory, swaps.
        int pair_a = preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser];
        int pair_b = preferences[pairs[i+1].winner][pairs[i+1].loser];
        if (pair_a < pair_b)
        {
// Create variable to temporarily hold values of switched pair
            pair tempswitch;
            tempswitch.winner = pairs[i].winner;
            tempswitch.loser = pairs[i].loser;
// In case of first pair being smaller than second pair, swap.
            pairs[i].winner = pairs[i+1].winner;
            pairs[i].loser = pairs[i+1].loser;
            pairs[i+1].winner = tempswitch.winner;
            pairs[i+1].loser = tempswitch.loser;
            swap_counter++;
        }
    }
    //  Each index specifies a pair with a winner and loser
    // Winner has the greatest number in the preferences matrix
    // Sort pairs by
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{

// [Alice Bob Charlie]
// Create loop to use as starting point for circle detection
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
// Initialize temp variable as the loser of the starting point
        int temp_variable = pairs[i].loser;
// initialize loopdetect and hitcount
        int infLoopDetector = 0;
        int hit_count = 0;
        while (infLoopDetector < pair_count)
        {
// While loop has 2 exit conditions:
// Exit 1: # of loops exceeds the number of actual pairs. Circle present in the code -- exit while loop and report i as troublemaker
// Exit 2: Dead end in which an unequivocal loser was found (no winning relationships). No hits after running j loop = exit
// if pair is locked, can iterate through it
// if pair is not locked, don't iterate through it
            hit_count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
            {
                if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == true || j == i)
                {
                    if (temp_variable == pairs[j].winner)
                    {
                        temp_variable = pairs[j].loser;
                        hit_count++;
                        infLoopDetector++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hit_count == 0 && infLoopDetector < pair_count)
            {
                locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (infLoopDetector == pair_count)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any info or guidance is appreciated.

I am expecting that, in a situation where the last pair to be locked would create a loop, I would get something like the following:

When i = the index of the last pair
Looping through j loop should yield a "hit". The temp variable should change to accommodate this new hit and execute the j loop again for other hits. It will find another one, and another one. This process should repeat until the infloopdetector reaches the pair count, and the while loop will exit. The pair will not be locked.

Comment: Did you `"Sort the pairs of candidates in decreasing order of strength of victory, where strength of victory is defined to be the number of voters who prefer the preferred candidate"`? If so, with 3-candidates (Alice, Bob, Charlie), a cycle can only occur when you attempt to lock the last pair.  Go through [CS50 - Tideman](https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2022/spring/psets/3/tideman/) carefully. The 9-vote cycle example in the middle.  On the last vote, if a cycle can be created, you don't lock that pair.

Comment: Also, please provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The issue leading to your problem could be elsewhere. Doesn't `locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;` mark the edge of the "winning" candidate instead of the "losing" one? (that's why we need to see how you treat `pairs` and `locked` in the rest of your code)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have attempted to provide the minimal complete reproducible example. This is the first time I have done something like this so let me know if anything additional is missing.